# List secrets used by certain pod in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I'd like to know if `kubectl` offers an easy way to list all the secrets that a certain pod/deployment/statefulset is using, or if there is some way to cleanly retrieve this info. When doing a `kubectl describe` for a pod, I see I can get a list of mounted volumes which include the ones that come from secrets that I could extract using `jq` and the like, but this way feels a bit clumsy. I have been searching a bit to no avail. Do you know if there is anything like that around? Perhaps using the API directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [List all Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) currently in use by a pod use:

```
kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[].spec.containers[].env[]?.valueFrom.secretKeyRef.name' | grep -v null | sort | uniq
```

In the other hand if you want to access to stored secrets in the API:

> Kubernetes Secrets are, by default, stored unencrypted in the API
> server's underlying data store (etcd). Anyone with API access can
> retrieve or modify a Secret, and so can anyone with access to etcd.
> Additionally, anyone who is authorized to create a Pod in a namespace
> can use that in order to safely use Secrets, take at least the
> following steps:
>
> - Enable Encryption at Rest for Secrets.
> - Enable or configure RBAC rules that restrict reading data in Secrets    (including via indirect means).
> - Where appropriate, also use mechanisms such as RBAC to limit which    principals are allowed to create new Secrets or replace existing
>   ones.access to read any Secret in that namespace; this includes
>   indirect access such as the ability to create a Deployment.

If you want more information about secrets in kubernetes, [follow this link.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to mark your answer as accepted! A slip from my side. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, that really helped
I suggest adding `-r` in the `jq` command, so you can use the result as input for some other command.